# How to simplify √x when used as exponent?

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-sum

Could anyone help me understand how to simplify the following expression.

$$x^\sqrt x$$

If there was a number instead of $\sqrt x$ as an exponent, it wouldn't be a problem for me. But I have never seen $\sqrt x$ as an exponent before.

Here's the original question:

> If $$x^{x^\sqrt x} = (x\sqrt x)^x,$$ what's the value of $x$?

Please **NOTICE** that **$\sqrt x$ on the LEFT** is an **exponent of exponent**.

Comment: Please use Mathjax for formatting a mathematical formula. Check if my edits are what you had in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$x\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac32}$$

Thus, you have:
$$x^{(x^\sqrt x)}=x^{\frac32x}$$

which gives $$x^\sqrt x=\frac32x\tag1$$

Also don't forget the trivial solution $x=1$

---

Further hint:

You can rearrange $(1)$ to $$x=(\log_x(\frac32)+1)^2$$
and, since we have isolated an $x$ term, we can  iterate:

$$x_{k+1}=(\log_{x_k}(\frac32)+1)^2$$

Set $x_0=\frac32$ and you will see this converges to $\frac 94$

Can you isolate another $x$ term in $1$ to gain another iteration formula?

Comment: Could you please tell me what you meant by trivial solution. However, I understand up until this point $x^√x = 3x/2$. But what to do next?

Comment: Edited question on next steps. A 'trivial' solution is one which can be spotted before needing to be worked out. Observing $1^k=1$ for any $k$ means it clearly satisfies the equation

Comment: I understand what you meant by 'trivial solution'. Unfortunately, I'm not good at math and I hardly understand logarithm. I didn’t understand the logarithm equation you added after 'Further hint'. Is there any simple way to do this without logarithm or do I need to learn logarithm first?

Comment: $x^y=z$ is the same as saying $\log_x(z)=y$. So when I had $x^{\sqrt x}=\frac32x$, I divide by $x$, so $x^{\sqrt x-1}=\frac 32$. Using the log definition above, we have $\sqrt x - 1=\log_x(\frac32)$. You don't need $\log$ for the other iteration.

Comment: If your problem is with iteration, use your calculator for that. Type $\frac32$ in and enter to set it as the last answer (which you can get by using Ans key). Then type out the RHS of my iteration, replacing '$x_k$' with 'Ans' and hit = repeatedly, you'll see the results approach $2.25$

Answer (score 1):

To simplify $x^{\sqrt{x}}$, you can try $\exp(\sqrt{x} \ln x)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so good at math. I didn't understand what you wanted me to do. Could you please explain. If you could avoid logarithm, that will be great.

Comment: If you need to avoid logarithms for this problem, yer gonna have a bad time

Answer (score 1):

## Hint:

Write $x\sqrt x= x^{3/2} $

Hence, $x^{x^\sqrt x}=x^{3x/2} \Rightarrow x^\sqrt x=3x/2 \Rightarrow x^{\sqrt x-1} =\frac{3} {2} \Rightarrow x=9/4$ is one of the solutions.

Comment: Perhaps you could show how you jumped from $x^{\sqrt x -1}=\frac32$ to $x=\frac94$. Also there's another two solutions :)

Comment: Could you please explain how did we get $x$ from $x^(√x-1)$.

Comment: @Russell,  I noticed that $x^{\sqrt x-1} =3/2 \Rightarrow (\sqrt x)^{2(\sqrt x - 1)} = \sqrt (\frac{9}{4})^1$

Comment: @Rhys Hughes, you are right. But the OP said in one of his comments that he was not comfortable at using logarithms. So I tried to answer without using logarithms. Thanks.